# Some android api calls (eg addView) simply stop working

Tags: android

I'm having some bizzare problems with my android app:
Sometimes I get a SIGSEGV error and some crash in the native rendering api for android.
I was not able to reproduce it, it was random.

(I do not use any native stuff, pure java).

Now, I rooted my phone to siyah and I didn't get the SIGSEGV crash but instead something even more bizzare: some api calls to android simply stopped working.

Eg I set all images/ui/content views but when I call, for example:

```
this.removeAllViews();
this.addView(view);
```

It simply doesn't work (this should show some other menu, but it is as if the code just isn't called down the line somewhere in the android OS code).

### ------------------

Another strange example: I have a drawer menu and there are two ways to close it:

1) By pressing on an image that has a onClick callback -> calls the close drawer function

2) By clicking an item in the drawer menu, the drawer item has a callback -> calls the close drawer function

I can close the drawer by using method 1), but it won't close for method 2).
Both codes DO run the drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView) code.

This is what makes this problem so strange.

I do use threading & synchronization, but all of this code for both cases run on the main ui thread.

I have the app locked in this state, any suggestion what I should do??

I was able to narrow it down to something having to do with the drawer menu closing (I execute the code to show next menu then), because I also got the SIGSEGVs when the drawer menu closed (it happen just as it was closing, so it always crashed during the close animation or just as it closed).

Comment: Have you tried `view.invalidate();` then `view.requestLayout();`?

Comment: But still this doesn't explain why it works in 99.9% of time.